# Problem with Ubuntu Software v 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-center

I have 3 problems with Ubuntu Software in v 20.04 LTS
1. I am only presented with the list for Editors Choice. None of the other tabs are available 
[image: screengrab 1]
[image]

2. I tried to install a code editor that I've been using for several versions of Ubuntu with no problem but was not installed on the upgrade. When trying to do so via Ubuntu Software it gets to 100% and then a dialog box opens stating that it is unable to find a folder usr/share/appdata even though that folder exists.
3. After the dialog box has opened it will NOT close and hovers over any other window that Ubuntu Software has open

Any answers to solve these would be gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: Does it work fine with a live USB?

Comment: not tried with a live usb @SasukeUchiha . I downloaded v20.04 and made a bootable usb to upgrade my v18.04 but the new version would not load some older progs.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just search for the software. Just type or click the search icon in top left and search.

2)Try installing through the terminal. `sudo apt-get <packagename>`  or if it is a snap `snap install <packagename>`

3) Click the *x* button!

Comment: yes I can do that but that's not sorting out the problems. 1. The app Ubuntu Software is not working correctly and 2. there is the error that is keeping the pop-up dialog open.

Comment: @patchworks101 Does the popup come for all packages?

Comment: no, only certain ones, and it's not always the same pop-up. In addition to the above I received one telling me that the prog' could not be installed due to a directory being locked, error 409. I've just reported the problems to Tech' Support for their info.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to first close **Software Center**,
2. Open **System Monitor** and end the process named **snap-store**.
3. Start **Software Center** again. Software Center will regenerate catalog.

This quick fix worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, problem solved. Telecom technician fixed a problem on the line which was restricting download speeds.